# Visual Studio cannot publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I tried this with a new project just to confirm that I have not made any errors, but Visual Studio 2019 won't publish any dot net core project. Below is the error I am getting... Any help would be much appreciated...

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       The "TransformAppSettings" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
>      at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.AppSettingsTransform.UpdateDestinationConnectionStringEntries(String destinationAppSettingsFilePath, ITaskItem[] destinationConnectionStrings)
>      at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.TransformAppSettings.TransformAppSettingsInternal()
>      at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.TransformAppSettings.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. ProjectNameX        0

Here is my project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
      <UserSecretsId>aspnet-ProjectNameX-A0D4A38F-C3FA-4FD3-8EBC-0F2201FBCD57</UserSecretsId>
      <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
      <DockerfileContext>..\..\..</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19307.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19307.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19307.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.7.12" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

While digging into visual studio folders, I found this...

[image: Nuget Folders in the Visual Studio folders, with Newtonsoft.Json dll file]

Comment: Can you show the project csproj file?

Comment: Hey @Stefan I have added it

Comment: Hmm... looks okay. Which settings do you use during publish?

Comment: Newtonsoft Json is not added in package, there is no PackageReference which points to Newtonsoft Json library

Comment: I have used Frame-Dependent & Portable since I aim to host on Linux in another machine

Comment: I am not sure where to add it @SnakeEyes

Comment: Visual Studio asks for 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' and I have version '12.0.2' already installed. I cannot downgrade...

Comment: @GithithuWambura I found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996326/the-transformappsettings-task-failed-unexpectedly), looks like this issue is about .net core 3.0 preview6?

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? If you have any discovery or answer feel free to share it here:)

Answer (score 1):

Please check if `Newtonsoft.Json`is referenced in your solution. It seems solution is not able to find it.

Below link shows how to add it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

Comment: However I am wondering should I add the Newtonsoft.Json Net version or Net Core version?

Comment: @GithithuWambura in below link, in answers, there are steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230014/why-cant-i-add-the-newtonsoft-json-dll-ref-to-my-project

Comment: I already have the library added by the 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI' library dependency. But thanks for your try... I appreciate... its still not working...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try publishing using a different Visual Studio 2019 instance? Not with the preview version of course.

Comment: It is a new project, I haven't editted anything. Though if i try to publish it with the cmd, it works fine...

Comment: Can you try publishing using a different Visual Studio 2019 instance? Not with the preview version of course.

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with your project. The error message "clearly" says that `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.TransformAppSettings.TransformAppSettingsInternal()` tried to access Newtonsoft.Json. This is obviously not your code.

I find this very strange, as `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.dll` exists in the same directory as `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` (check c:\program files\dotnet\sdk), and it should have been compiled against the same version that ships. You can confirm using something like ILSpy to see what the assembly version of Newtonsoft.Json is and what assembly reference the publish tasks dll has. You can also better understand the paths and dlls that .NET used to try to load the dll, and why any dll with a matching filename was not used, using Fusion Logs. But I'm not going to write a tutorial on using Fusion Logs here.

In any case, understanding why it's happening won't help you solve it. All you can really do is make sure you're using the latest SDK, install the newest version if not, and if the problem still exists using the Visual Studio "report a problem" tool to let the .NET Core team know about this.

Comment: it is not the SDK issue, since I can publish my project via Powershell

dotnet publish --configuration Release --framework netcoreapp2.2,

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue.

In package manager console execute: `Update-Package –reinstall Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: Hey, here is it's feedback...

No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'src\ProjectNameX'.

Answer (score 0):

Though you haven't added package reference in .csproj. Open the `project.assets.json` file in your obj folder and search for `Newtonsoft.Json` you would find the real version you refer to.

So just check if [binding redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) can help. If not, check if this issue persists if you create a new .net core empty web-app. Then publish it to locate the issue according to the result whether it succeeds or not.